# Access returned array works on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, arrays, function

This works on localhost but not on server:

```
$x = preg_split("/#/", $val)[0];
```

I have wasted like 4 hours to notice that this was the problem. On the server no errors were shown and the php file was interpreted in a very strange way, if I had a `die('ok')` before this line it won't show anything.

```
$x = preg_split("/#/", $val);
$x = $x[0];
```

Works on server too.

And it's not about `preg_split`, it is the same with every function that returns an array.

Comment: The server does not seem to run PHP 5.4: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php.

Comment: Have you tried checking your server’s error_log for Fatal errors?

Comment: Yes, no errors in error log.

Comment: @FelixKling has given you the answer - you're using a feature of PHP 5.4 therefore the server must be running < PHP 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running php 5.4 on localhost but php 5.3 (or some other) on the server

Function array dereferencing was added on php 5.4 see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

Comment: Oh, the server is on 5.2.17 ... Need to have a talk with the hosting company :) .